# Build pandas filter from a config file

Tags: python, pandas

I need to parametrize a pandas filter from a file, I picked YAML for the sake of it.
I have the following file:

```
is_athletic:
   condition_1:
       or:
           - and:
               - goes_gym
               - not_overweight
           - is_below_20
           - and:
               - buys_supplements
               - is_local
```

So I am able to read this dictionary and have a code that would be equivalent to:

```
if ((df['goes_gym'] == 1 and df['not_overweight'] == 1) or (df['is_below_20'] == 1) 
or ((df['buys_supplements'] == 1) and (df['is_local'] == 1))):
df['is_athletic_1'] = True
```

What is a good approach to achieve this

Comment: Do you know the method [`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)? Instead of build the python code, you just have to create the query string.

Comment: @Corralien That seems like a valid approach, if you could provide a small example I would def take it as a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample:

```
>>> df

         name  goes_gym  not_overweight  is_below_20  buys_supplements  is_local
0       Chase         1               1            1                 1         1
1     Othilie         1               1            1                 1         1
2      Mariya         1               1            1                 1         1
3      Derron         0               0            0                 0         0
4     Gerardo         1               0            0                 0         1
5        Aldo         0               0            0                 1         0
6       Bryan         1               1            1                 0         1
7    Stoddard         0               0            1                 1         0
8      Karole         0               1            1                 1         0
9      Morris         1               1            0                 0         1
10  Modestine         1               0            0                 0         0
11      Angus         1               0            1                 1         1
12     Karole         0               1            1                 1         0
13      Nelie         1               0            0                 1         1
14   Nicholle         0               1            0                 0         0
```

Evaluate query string from dict (or YAML):

```
d = {'is_athletic': '(goes_gym == 1 and not_overweight == 1) or is_below_20 == 1 or (buys_supplements == 1 and is_local == 1)'}

for col, qs in d.items():
    df[col] = 0
    df.loc[df.query(qs).index, col] = 1
```

Output:

```
>>> df[['name', col]]

         name  is_athletic
0       Chase            1
1     Othilie            1
2      Mariya            1
3      Derron            0
4     Gerardo            0
5        Aldo            0
6       Bryan            1
7    Stoddard            1
8      Karole            1
9      Morris            1
10  Modestine            0
11      Angus            1
12     Karole            1
13      Nelie            1
14   Nicholle            0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, just out of curiosity, why the .index when doing the query?

Comment: This is the index of the row (0..14) where to set update (set to 1)